# Find column with most matches across multiple columns R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that looks like this:

```
   id   a   b   c
1 346 BBX BBX RRS
2 677 BBX TFT TFT
3 999 BBX CAT CAT
```

What I want to do is: for each row, find the value across a,b,c that has the most matches. So the result would look like this:

```
   id   y
1 346 BBX
2 677 TFT
3 999 CAT
```

If there are cases where there is no column with more matches than any other, I am indifferent to which value is chosen.

Any suggestions?

I also got as far as transforming the data in the manner below, and creating a variable "n", for the number of occurrences of each x. But not sure how "select" the x with highest n for each id.

```
   id  x   n
1 346 BBX  2
2 346 RRS  1
3 677 BBX  1
4 677 TFT  2
5 999 BBX  1
6 999 CAT  2
```

Here's some code the data:

```
id <- c("346", "677", "999")
a <- rep ("BBX", 3)
b <- c("BBX", "TFT", "CAT")
c <- c("RRS", "TFT", "CAT")
x <- data.frame(id, a,b,c, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

or

```
id <- c("346", "346", "677", "677", "999", "999")
x <- c("BBX", "RRS", "BBX", "TFT", "BBX", "CAT")
n <- c("2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2")
bl <- data.frame(id, x, n)
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already pivot it longer, you can use top_n, like this:

```
x %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>% group_by(id) %>%  
count(value) %>% arrange(id,-n) %>% 
filter(!duplicated(id))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    value     n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 346   BBX       2
2 677   TFT       2
3 999   CAT       2
```

If you have NAs, for example, you can try to filter them out:

```
x[1,3:4]= NA
x %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
count(value) %>% arrange(id,-n) %>% 
filter(!duplicated(id))
```

Or in base R, you can apply a sort(table(..)) function row-wise:

```
most_freq = apply(x[,-1],1,function(i)names(sort(-table(i)))[1])
data.frame(id=x$id,most_freq)
   id most_freq
1 346       BBX
2 677       TFT
3 999       CAT
```

Comment: The 2nd approach will work. Let me check for the first one.. Your NAs need be NA, and not "NA"

Comment: Thank you!! This seems to be working - just that it is not selecting a single value in the cases where there are values of a,b,c that match/occur an equal number of times. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: Ok, I guess we cannot use top_n, the alternative is to count, and then sort everything by n. and we take the first id that we see.. Then again, is your order of id important for the result?

Comment: Ok @nred i have corrected it.. it's sorted by id then counts now

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for